# Why does data_class leads to LogicException?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.5

I have a form type (field_type) which extends text and have a **data_class**. Passing an entity instance to the form via event listener leads to a *LogicException*:

> The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class Entity,
>   but is a(n) string. You can avoid this error by setting the
>   "data_class" option to null or by adding a view transformer that
>   transforms a(n) string to an instance of Entity.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('field', 'field_type', $opts);

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) use($options)
    {
        ...
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $form->get('field')->setData($entity);
    });
}
```

`$entity` is an instance of the **data_class**. The form type has a view data transformer, too.

Field type:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->addViewTransformer($this->viewTransformer, true);
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Entity',
        'invalid_message' => 'The given id is invalid!',
        'required' => true
    ));
}

public function getParent()
{
    return 'text';
}
```

Everything works fine except the part of the **data_class**. If I remove the **data_class** it works.

Why do I need to remove this part?